# form submitting html content with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<form id="form1">
<ul>
<li>Content</li>
<li>Content</li>
<li>Content</li>
</ul>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I want to send the content in the ul tag when clicking the submit button.

the submitted data should be

```
<li>Content</li>
<li>Content</li>
<li>Content</li>
```

How would I write this in jquery and with proper char. escaping for the <>'s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: This is an alternative to my other AJAX based answer.

You can do this by setting the value of a hidden field with javascript. Also, your form needs an "action" attribute - it has to be submitted to somewhere.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<form action="/my_script.php" id="my_id">
  <ul>
    Stuff...
  </ul>
  <input type="hidden" name="html />
</form>
```

The script:

```
$("#my_id").submit(function () {
  var html = $(this).find("ul").html();
  $(this).find("input[name=html]").val(escape(html));
  // don't return false, we want the submit event to go through
});
```

The form will submit, and the hidden field will have the escaped HTML from the `<ul></ul>` tag as value.

Answer (score 3):

To hook the submit, do this:

```
$("#form1").submit(function () {
  // do stuff
  return false;
});
```

Replace the `// do stuff` part with one of the following:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "...",
  type: "POST",
  data: $("#form1 ul").html()
});
```

If you want to escape it, I'd do it on the server side. You can also do this, to perform a client side escape:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "...",
  type: "POST",
  data: escape($("#form1 ul").html())
});
```

I think the most elegant solution would be to send it as JSON to the server.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "...",
  dataType: "json",
  // the value of `type` is irrelevant here
  data: {html: $("#form1 ul").html(), moreMetadDtaIfYouWant: 5}
});
```

But that's your call ;)

Comment: Can raw HTML actually be serialized into a query string?  Even if it works, I don't see how the server would be able to accept a request like this.  It has to be in a form field, whether it's a "real" form field or a manually-assembled query string.

Comment: Good point, it wouldn't actually work. If it was a POST request, it would, though. The escaped (or not escaped) HTML would just be the raw post body. In, say, a rails app, you would have to use `request.body` instead of `params[:something]`. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: can this be a normal request, not ajax? I would like it to reload the page just like with a normal form.   return false; is preventing that

Comment: Sure, I'll post another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you're going to have to submit your values inside some form field so you're going to first have to create a input of some type, probably hidden if I had to venture a guess, with in your form.

```
<input id="your_id" type="hidden" />
```

Then using jquery you could do this in the onSubmit of the form...

```
$("#form1").submit(function(){
  $("#your_id").val($("#form1 ul").html());
}
```

I'm not sure if the form will automatically escape the html you're submitting or not though.

Comment: hmm.. data in the hidden field is never posted

Comment: probably because your form doesn't have an "action" attribute. At least not the one you refer to in your question.